# Powershell Read mysql pass read value to a run a CMD command

Tags: mysql, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need a PowerShell script to call back the last MySQL record in the table, read its ID, then loop and if record ID has increased, pass each new record value to cmd console.

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  1234    |
+----+----------+
| 2  |  12345   |
+----+----------+
| 3  |  123456  |
+----+----------+
```

This is what I have so far:

```
MySQL.ps1 -Query "SELECT id FROM events_guests WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM events_guests)"
```

Which returns:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
```

That is the latest ID in the table, and if I run:

```
MySQL.ps1 -Query "SELECT username FROM events_guests WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM events_guests)"
```

I can get the username that I need to pass to a cmd console.

```
+----------+
| username |
+----------+
|  123456  |
+----------+
```

What command do I need to keep looping if there are more records & how do I call a cmd command like net user %username% password for each record?

Comment: If you are getting the last record, how could there be more records? Or are you wanting to have it just keep checking for more records and run the CMD whenever there is a new record?

Comment: Yes, that is correct sorry, it should keep looping looking for new records. If it was 3 and now is 5 then run cmd command with username value of 4 &5.

Comment: You need to store the ID from the current run somewhere so you can check against it in the next run: `SELECT username FROM events_guests WHERE id > $last_id`.

Comment: Try `help for` and look at your options.